# Why does my element not change style on hover?

Tags: html, css, styles

I know other people have had similar problems but their solutions do not work.
What is the reason for the following?

```
div.line_container:hover #sidebar_loader1 {
z-index: 2;
}
```

the above code does change the z-index.

```
div:hover #sidebar_loader1 {
z-index: 2;
}
```

but this one does.

what is the reason for this because i need to know because i need only that class when hovered to change a style. Please help.

MY HTML code

```
<img src="" alt="image" id="logo">

<div class="line_container">
    <img src="http://png.findicons.com/files/icons/1580/devine_icons_part_2/128/png.png" alt="IMAGE" class="line_image">
    <span class="line_text">
        THIS IS SOME SAMPLE TEXT >
    </span>
</div>

<div class="sidebar_loader" id="sidebar_loader1">
    TEST for 1
</div>

<div class="line_container">
    <img src="http://png.findicons.com/files/icons/1580/devine_icons_part_2/128/png.png" alt="IMAGE" class="line_image">
    <span class="line_text">
        THIS IS SOME SAMPLE TEXT >
    </span>
</div>

<div class="sidebar_loader" id="sidebar_loader2">
    TEST for 2
</div>

<div class="line_container">
    <img src="http://png.findicons.com/files/icons/1580/devine_icons_part_2/128/png.png" alt="IMAGE" class="line_image">
    <span class="line_text">
        THIS IS SOME SAMPLE TEXT >
    </span>
</div>

<div class="sidebar_loader" id="sidebar_loader3">
    TEST for 3
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: without HTML markup we can't tell anything.

Comment: From a straight CSS standpoint, it should work just fine, what you have done is not incorrect.  The likely scenario is the selector you are using already has a z-index value on hover, and your style isn't overwriting it.

Comment: I have uploaded the code. PLEASE HELP

Comment: `div.line_container:hover #sidebar_loader1` says `#sidebar_loader1` has to be a child of `div.line_container` which is not the case. It's not a child, it's a sibling. Change the selector to `div.line_container:hover ~ #sidebar_loader1`

Comment: When you use the second it is working because you are also hovering on the top div with `#side_bar_container`.

Comment: @NicoO thanks that is correct. what selector would i need for    #line_container1:hover > #side_bar_container{
   width:50px;
  }

Comment: @KheemaPandey please help. I now need to know how to change the side_bar_container width when i hover #sidebar_loader1.

Comment: seriously? this selector (`>`) would also require `#side_bar_container` to be a child of `.line_container`.  When you dont want to change your html use `div.line_container:hover ~ #sidebar_loader1 { width:50px; }`. Read this: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors seems to be much, but it's  essential knowledge.

Comment: @NicoO that doesnt work and i checked the website and have ttried everything but it still doesnt work. please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#sidebar_loader_1` is *not* a descendant of `div.line_container`, so using the descendant combinator (space) is incorrect.

Try the sibling combinator. Either `+` or `~` should work.

Comment: Thank you so much. I cant believe i forgot that. THANKS THANKS THANKS

Comment: also, can i ask you how to do this selection properly

Comment: line_container #side_bar_container{
   width:50px;
  }

Answer (score 1):

The div with id `sidebar_loader1` is not nested in any div with a class `line_container`

Comment: what would i need to do for line_container #side_bar_container{ width:50px; }